# Pandas - Conditional Column Creation based on the Last working day of the week

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame like this,

```
date       day_of_wk    wk_num  wkend_hol_ind   freq_daily
1/1/2007    Monday        1         H   
1/2/2007    Tuesday       1         H   
1/3/2007    Wednesday     1                       D
1/4/2007    Thursday      1                       D
1/5/2007    Friday        1                       D
1/6/2007    Saturday      1         W   
1/7/2007    Sunday        1         W   
1/8/2007    Monday        2                       D
1/9/2007    Tuesday       2                       D
1/10/2007   Wednesday     2                       D
1/11/2007   Thursday      2                       D
1/12/2007   Friday        2         H     
1/13/2007   Saturday      2         W
1/14/2007   Sunday        2         W
```

I am trying to create a new column inside the data frame as "freq_weekly".

This column will have a value of "W" for the last value of "D" for each value of "wk_num" and blank for other columns.

for example, 1/5/2017 will have a value "W" and 1/11/2017 will have a value "W". Others will have blanks in it.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create helper `mask` for consecutive groups by `ne`, `shift` and `cumsum`, then filter only `D` rows and get last values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='last'`, then excluded rows by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
m = df['freq_daily'].eq('D')
mask = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m].duplicated(keep='last').reindex(df.index, fill_value=True)
```

If need test more columns for duplicates:

```
mask = (df.assign(m=m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum())[m]
          .duplicated(['wk_num','freq_daily'],keep='last')
          .reindex(df.index, fill_value=True))
```

So possible create new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['freq_weekly'] = np.where(mask, '', 'W')
print (df)
         date  day_of_wk  wk_num wkend_hol_ind freq_daily freq_weekly
0    1/1/2007     Monday       1             H        NaN            
1    1/2/2007    Tuesday       1             H        NaN            
2    1/3/2007  Wednesday       1           NaN          D            
3    1/4/2007   Thursday       1           NaN          D            
4    1/5/2007     Friday       1           NaN          D           W
5    1/6/2007   Saturday       1             W        NaN            
6    1/7/2007     Sunday       1             W        NaN            
7    1/8/2007     Monday       2           NaN          D            
8    1/9/2007    Tuesday       2           NaN          D            
9   1/10/2007  Wednesday       2           NaN          D            
10  1/11/2007   Thursday       2           NaN          D           W
11  1/12/2007     Friday       2             H        NaN            
12  1/13/2007   Saturday       2             W        NaN            
13  1/14/2007     Sunday       2             W        NaN
```